# Why view is not updated if my table definition is updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a table as the definition below:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    a INT,
    b INT
)
```

And after that, I am creating a view on the table as:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewTest
AS
SELECT * FROM Test
```

After that, when I run the query on view, it returns me with two columns i.e. `A & B`.

And, later I update the definition of table and insert a new column in it:

```
ALTER TABLE Test ADD c INT
```

But now when I run the view, it again returns the view statement, it returns me the same number of columns, not three columns.

**I just wanted to know why? Because I have used the Select * statement, so every time it should return me with the whole of columns.**

Comment: That's how it's specified. And I say its great that views doesn't change if a column is added at a later stage!

Comment: I just wanted to know why? Because i have used the Select * statement, so everytime it should return me with the whole of columns.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The metadata for the view (i.e. the names and types of columns) are only resolved once, when the view is created. If the underlying table(s) change later on, the view must be recreated to reflect the changes.

Comment: select * is for ad-hoc queries, not for programming. I suppose the reason is to "preserve" the view (in case of later table changes.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a view it stores the view definition as metadata in the system tables. Even if you use `SELECT * FROM` it will store the exact column names e.g. `SELECT a, b FROM`

If you then update the base table the metadata definition for the view still remains the same so any new columns won't be picked up.

You need to either drop and recreate the view or run [sp_refreshview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187821.aspx) to update the definition

Answer (score 2):

When you add new columns to Test, ViewTest already exists, and only has columns A and B. You'd have to drop ViewTest and re-create it for your "SELECT *" statement to retrieve the new column C.

Answer (score 2):

This does seem like unexpected behavior when you first encounter it.  It is quite well-documented.  For instance, in the documentation for [`CREATE VIEW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> If a view is not created with the SCHEMABINDING clause, sp_refreshview
>   should be run when changes are made to the objects underlying the view
>   that affect the definition of the view. Otherwise, the view might
>   produce unexpected results when it is queried.

Recompiling is easy . . . you can use `alter view` or `sp_refreshview` (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx)).

The two options are:

- Define the view with SCHEMABINDING to *prevent* changes to the tables used in the view.
- *Manually* modify the view after the tables change.

I suspect this is an optimization in SQL Server, so when you use a view, the engine can just plug in compiled code, instead of doing a bunch of integrity checks on the tables being used.  This optimization is important for views used in transactional processing.  It is not so important if you are running more complex queries through the view.  However, this doesn't explain why the checks aren't done when the underlying tables change.

I have been bitten by this in a bad way in the past, when underlying tables changed and the resulting `select` had the wrong offsets for the columns.  Note that this problem is *not* fixed just by avoiding `select *`, although that is generally a good practice.

Also, if you have a large system that runs periodically (say, weekly or daily), you might want to put in a job that recompiles all views in the system.  This also ensures that their execution plans are updating for more recent statistics on tables.  And, if you really want to be careful, use `SCHEMABINDING` so any changes to the underlying tables need to be done deliberately.

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN documentation:

**[View Definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)**

Creates a virtual table whose contents (columns and rows) are defined by a query. Use this statement to create a view of the data in one or more tables in the database. For example, a view can be used for the following purposes:

- To focus, simplify, and customize the perception each user has of the database.
- As a security mechanism by allowing users to access data through the view, without granting the users permissions to directly access the underlying base tables.
- To provide a backward compatible interface to emulate a table whose schema has changed.

This tree itens from the [View Definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) docs should answer you why. Mostly precise the iten 3 of it.

It is also not a good pratice to create a view with `select *` because exactly the changes you or anyone else that look at the view will not know what columns it have.

There is also a note on that docs:

**Note**

> Any updates performed directly to a view's underlying tables are not verified against the view, even if CHECK OPTION is specified.